# Problem using ExtJS InsertHtml in IE to append multiple <tr>to a table

Tags: html, internet-explorer, extjs

It seems that when you try to append multiple  into a table in IE using ExtJs (Sencha) InsertHtml function, it will only create the first .

Example:

```
<script>
 Ext.get('bob').insertHtml('afterEnd','<tr><td>blih</td></tr><tr><td>bluh</td></tr>');
</script>

<table>
 <tr id='bob'>
  <td>blah</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

You will only have:

```
<table>
 <tr id='bob'>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td>blih</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? It only happens in IE...

Comment: What version of IE and ExtJs are you using?  It works for me using IE8 and Ext 3.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that you're referencing 'bob' before it's been rendered in the DOM.  Try either moving your code below the HTML or wrapping it in an `Ext.onReady` block:

```
<script>
    Ext.onReady(function(){
        Ext.get('bob').insertHtml('afterEnd','<tr><td>blih</td></tr><tr><td>bluh</td></tr>');
    });
</script>
```